# How to Rank the Effects (Coefficients) of a Categorical Variable

Tags: logistic, anova, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have a categorical variable, 'Ethnicity' with 12 levels, and an output variable 'has_condition' stating whether a particular subject had a particular genetic condition (1 means favorable, 0 means unfavorable). I would like to see if a person's 'Ethnicity' is significantly related to 'has_condition'; in other words, if certain ethnic groups have stronger probabilities of having the condition than others. The ultimate goal is to rank the coefficients, indicating which groups are most likely to have the condition.

My original thought process was to build a logistic regression model, determine which ethnic groups were statistically significant, and rank the significant ones in order of their coefficient values. Then I realized that this doesn't necessarily provide a test for whether the coefficient *differences* are significant.

Then I suspected that maybe I should use a logistic regression model followed by a series of Wald tests to determine whether the coefficients are significantly different. This however seems like a fairly roundabout way of doing this kind of analysis and I suspected that there may be a better way.

I also considered building a series of logistic regression models, changing the held-out level in each one and noting the statistical significance and direction of each explanatory variable in each model. Again this seems fairly roundabout although I think it would probably work.

What is/are the most effective way(s) of handling this situation? Is it a different test outside of regression altogether? I considered ANOVA as well but it seemed like doing a Tukey HSD comparison for each group would be just as roundabout and computationally expensive as a series of Wald tests. I also considered doing a $\chi^2$ test  of independence but this still requires many additional post-hoc tests to figure out the order of how impactful the different levels of the independent variable are.

Am I underestimating the complexity of this problem? Is there a standard methodology for handling these types of situations? Are the approaches I listed above valid?

For reference, my standard computing environment is generally either numpy/scipy/pandas or R.